# Provide tab title with reportlab generated pdf

Tags: python, django, pdf-generation, httpresponse, reportlab

This question is really simple, but I can't find any data on it.
When I generate a pdf with reportlab, passing the httpresponse as a file, browsers that are configured to show files display the pdf correctly. However, the title of the tab remains "(Anonymous) 127.0.0.1/whatnot", which is kinda ugly for the user.

Since most sites are able to somehow display an appropiate title, I think it's doable... Is there some sort of title parameter that I can pass to the pdf? Or some header for the response? This is my code:

```
def render_pdf_report(self, context, file_name):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="{}"'.format(file_name)

    document = BaseDocTemplate(response, **self.get_create_document_kwargs())
    #  pdf generation code
    document.build(story)
    return response
```

Comment: Can you provide any examples of those sites where it is working as you want it to?

Comment: eg: here, the filename is displayed in the title http://www.biblioteca.org.ar/libros/211756.pdf . Also, when generating with weasyprint, the html title tag is addressed, so I'm positive it's doable

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seems that Google Chrome doesn't display the PDF titles at all.
I tested the link in your comment ([biblioteca.org.ar](http://www.biblioteca.org.ar/libros/211756.pdf)) and it displays in Firefox as " - 211756.pdf", seems there's an empty title and Firefox then just displays the filename instead of the full URL path.

I reproduced the same behaviour using this piece of code:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf")
c.setTitle("hello stackoverflow")
c.drawString(100, 750, "Welcome to Reportlab!")
c.save()
```

Opening it in Firefox yields the needed result:
[image]

I found out about `setTitle` in [ReportLab's User Guide](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf). It has it listed on page 16. :)

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do the trick. Now I should try to change this to work with platypus w/o using a canvas

Comment: And about the mention of setTitle in the docs.. it doesn't even explain what effect does it have nor does it help when you aren't using a canvas

Answer (score 6):

I was also looking for this and I found this in the source code.

reportlab/src/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py 
@ line - 467

We can set the document's title by

```
document.title = 'Sample Title'
```

Answer (score 5):

I realise this is an old question but dropping in an answer for anyone using `SimpleDocTemplate`. The `title` property can be set in constructor of `SimpleDocTemplate` as a kwarg. e.g.

```py
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_bytes, title="my_pdf_title")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using trml2pdf, you will need to add the "title" attribute in the template tag, ie., <template title="Invoices" ...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said, you can use

```
Canvas.setTitle("yourtitle")
```

which shows up fine in chrome.